# Standard-compliant way to define a floating-point equivalence relationship

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm aware of the usual issues with floating point arithmetic and precision loss, so this is not the usual question about why `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3` and the like.

Instead, I would actually like to implement a binary predicate in C++ (**in a 100% standard compliant way**) that actually implements a real mathematical [equivalence relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) (i.e. being reflexive, transitive, and symmetric), such that two doubles are in the same equivalence class if they represent the exact same value in all respects, distinguishing corner cases like `0.0` and `-0.0` but treating all `NaN` values as being in the same equivalence class. (In particular, the default `==` is not what I want because is is non-reflexive in the case of `NaN`, and does not distinguish between `0.0` and negative `-0.0`, which I would like to be in different equivalence classes, as they are actually different values and lead to different runtime behaviors).

What's the shortest and simplest way to do this that does not rely on type punning in any way or any implementation-defined behavior? So far I've got:

```
#include <cmath>

bool equiv(double x, double y)
{   
    return (x == y && (x != 0.0 || std::signbit(x) == std::signbit(y))) ||
           (std::isnan(x) && std::isnan(y));
}
```

I believe this handles the corner cases I know about and described earlier, but are there any other corner cases that this doesn't handle that I'm missing? And is the above binary predicate **guaranteed** to define an equivalence relationship according to the C++ standard, or is any of the behavior unspecified, implementation-defined, etc.?

Comment: NaNs can have different "NaN payloads", which are bitwise not identical, though you may not care.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I'm aware and don't care :) or more that I do care, but actually specifically want them to be equivalent for my purposes.

Comment: @Trantorian Did you think about using fixed point decimals instead?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's not the point of this exercise at all. This is to unit test an interchange format that isn't supposed to lose information (other than bitwise representation of NaNs). The format is defined as using floating-point numbers, though.

Comment: -0 and 0 *are* mathematically equivalent.

Comment: @davidhigh No, they actually behave differently. They're **defined** in IEEE to compare equal, but I specifically don't want that behavior, because I'm testing round-trip behavior of a serialization format.

Comment: but you'll get serious mathematical problems if you do. For example, is `-0 + 1 != 0 +1`?

Comment: @davidhigh I'm not sure you understand the point of this exercise. The point is to test that things round-trip through a serialization format without loss of information.

Comment: @davidhigh also `1.0 / 0.0` is positive infinity, but `1.0 / -0.0` is negative infinity, so the two are mathematically distinct.

Comment: then clear out the confusion and state the definition of your equivalence class. I'll try for one: two numbers are in the same equivalence class if their  bit representation is exactly identical. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @davidhigh I think I made explicit what I wanted in the question. The desired equivalence classes are such that floating point numbers with any distinct behavior are always in different classes. `0.0` and `-0.0` have distinct behaviors, so I want to make sure I don't lose that distinction upon serialization/deserialization. (Also, I know there are signaling and non-signaling NaNs, but for my purposes I consider them equivalent, as I specifically serialize them the same.)

Comment: @Trantorian: your `1/0` vs. `1/(-0)` argument is wrong. It's a case of definition, since none is inside in the ring where your multiplication is defined. But just go on, my comments shall not sound too negative ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77839/discussion-between-trantorian-and-davidhigh).

Comment: @davidhigh Please see my response in the chat and respond there, thanks.

Comment: `x != 0.0` is probably superfluous, but it looks correct to me

Comment: @Gerald it's not strictly necessary, I know: it just avoids calling `std::signbit` for anything other that +/-0.

Comment: True, but mostly inconsequential. I'd personally prefer to make the expression a little easier to read, but that's not particularly consequential here either :)

Comment: Do any of the computers involved use a non-IEEE754 floating point representation?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I'm not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "computers involved"? Are you asking in general if any such computers exist in the world, or are you specifically asking about the computers I am personally targeting myself with this code?

Comment: @Trantorian The latter. In other words, can you safely assume that `double` is IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan have to look at it, but I'm pretty sure I can -- targets are  Power, SPARC, and x86.

Comment: @Trantorian Those are all IEEE 754 floating point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks right.

You can actually get rid of function calls for platforms which implement IEEE 754 (Intel's, Power's and ARMs do) because the special floating point values can be determined without calls.

```
bool equiv(double x, double y) {
    return (x == y && (x || (1 / x == 1 / y))) || (x != x && y != y);
}
```

The above uses the fact that IEEE:

- Division of non-zero to zero yields infinity special values that retain the sign. Hence `1 / -0.` yields `-infinity`. Infinity special values with the same sign compare equal.
- NaNs do not compare equal.

The original version though, reads better for most people. Judging from interviewing experience, not every developer knows how special floating point values arise and behave.

If only NaNs had one representation you could just do `memcmp`.

---

With regards to C++ and C language standards, [The New C Standard](http://www.knosof.co.uk/cbook/cbook.html) book says:

> The term IEEE floating point is often heard. This usage came about because the original standards on this topic were published by the IEEE. This standard for binary floating-point arithmetic is what many host processors have been providing for over a decade. However, its use is not mandated by C99.
>
> The representation for binary floating-point specified in this standard is used by the Intel x86 processor family, Sun SPARC, HP PA-RISC, IBM P OWER PC, HP–was DEC – Alpha, and the majority of modern processors (some DSP processors support a subset, or make small changes, for cost/performance reasons; while others have more substantial differences e.g., TMS320C3x uses two’s complement). There is also a publicly available software implementation of this standard.
>
> Other representations are still supported by processors (IBM 390 and HP–was DEC – VAX) having an existing customer base that predates the publication the documents on which this standard is based. These representations will probably continue to be supported for some time because of the existing code that relies
>   on it (the IBM 390 and HP–was DEC– Alpha support both their companies respective older representations and the IEC 60559 requirements).
>
> There is a common belief that once the IEC 60559 Standard has been specified all of its required functionality will be provided by conforming implementations. It is possible that a C program’s dependencies on IEC 60559 constructs, which can vary between implementations, will not be documented because of this common, incorrect belief (the person writing documentation is not always the person who is familiar with this standard).
>
> Like the C Standard the IEC 60559 Standard does not fully specify the behavior of every construct. It also provides optional behavior for some constructs, such as when underflow is raised, and has optional constructs that an implementation may or may not make use of, such as double standard. C99 does not always provide a method for finding out an implementation’s behavior in these optional areas. For instance, there are no standard macros describing the various options for handling underflow.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) says:

> **Languages and Compilers**
>
> **Ambiguity**
>
> Ideally, a language definition should define the semantics of the language precisely enough to prove statements about programs. While this is usually true for the integer part of a language, language definitions often have a large grey area when it comes to floating-point. Perhaps this is due to the fact that many language designers believe that nothing can be proven about floating-point, since it entails rounding error. If so, the previous sections have demonstrated the fallacy in this reasoning. This section discusses some common grey areas in language definitions, including suggestions about how to deal with them.
>
> ... Another ambiguity in most language definitions concerns what happens on overflow, underflow and other exceptions. The IEEE standard precisely specifies the behavior of exceptions, and so languages that use the standard as a model can avoid any ambiguity on this point.
>
> ... Another grey area concerns the interpretation of parentheses. Due to round-off errors, the associative laws of algebra do not necessarily hold for floating-point numbers... Whether or not the language standard specifies that parenthesis must be honored, (x+y)+z can have a totally different answer than x+(y+z), as discussed above.
>
> .... rounding can be a problem. The IEEE standard defines rounding very precisely, and it depends on the current value of the rounding modes. This sometimes conflicts with the definition of implicit rounding in type conversions or the explicit round function in languages.

The language standards cannot possibly specify the results of floating point operations because, for example, one can change the rounding mode at run-time using [`std::fesetround`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround).

So C and C++ languages have no other choice but to map operations on floating point types directly to hardware instructions and not interfere, like they do. Hence, the languages do not copy IEEE/IEC standard and do not mandate it either.

Comment: But the C++ standard does not mandate IEEE 754 so I think it wouldn't meet the OP's requirements.

Comment: @5gon12eder C++ standard leaves floating point specification unspecified because it cannot copy IEEE in its entirety and track it.

Comment: I upvoted this but can you address in the question how much of this behavior is covered by which standards? In particular, does C++ define enough behavior of floating point numbers to ensure that this is an equivalence class, or does it leave all the relevant behaviors open to the implementation to decide such that there's no 100% standard way to guarantee what I want?

Comment: (I'm probably going to use mine or yours anyway, but I'm just asking for a better language-lawyer understanding of this issue.)

Comment: @Trantorian "Languages and Compilers" section in "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" cover this in detail. Too much to paste here.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin can you at least update your answer to say whether your answer is guaranteed correct by the C++ standard, or only guaranteed on platforms that additionally implement IEEE 754? I'm not clear on that.

Comment: @Trantorian I don't think this answer works for `-0.0, -0.0`.

Comment: I would stick with the std:: functions. There's not much value in micro-optimizing a unit test.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Your code seems to buggy actually. I think you meant `x > 0 == y > 0` rather than `x > 0 && y > 0`, but that also doesn't work for me (g++ on i386 Linux): `0.0` and `-0.0` are comparing equivalent. My original version works so I'm probably sticking with that.

Comment: @Trantorian Added more context and removed wrong code.

Comment: @Gerald yes, I am going to stick with my original, since that's working as I wanted and Maxim's is not.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I think you mean `(x == y && (x || (1 / x == 1 / y))) || (x != x && y != y)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77843/discussion-between-trantorian-and-maxim-egorushkin).