# C++ code crashing when using function instead of inline code

Tags: c++

C++ rookie here.

I have the following code:

```
std::vector<float> MyBuffer::readAverage(int numberOfBuffers) {
 std::vector<float> result = std::vector<float>(streams.size());
 for (int i = 0; i < streams.size(); ++i) {
    result[i] = getAverage(streams[i], numberOfBuffers);
 }
 return result;
}

float MyBuffer::getAverage(std::deque<float> input, int numberOfBuffers) {
 float sum = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBuffers; ++i) {
     sum += input[i];
 }
 return sum / numberOfBuffers;
}
```

This code randomly crashes at `getAverage()`, I am not sure why.

Strange thing (for me as a C++ rookie at least) is that when I inline the function, it does not crash:

```
std::vector<float> MyBuffer::readAverage(int numberOfBuffers) {
 std::vector<float> result = std::vector<float>(streams.size());
 for (int i = 0; i < streams.size(); ++i) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < numberOfBuffers; ++i1) {
        sum += streams[i][i1];
    }
    result[i] = sum / numberOfBuffers;
 }
 return result;
}
```

I can understand that there may be many reasons why this specific code is crashing - so my question relates more to what changes when I inline it, rather than calling a function? In my mind it should be exactly the same thing, but I guess there is something about the way C++ works that I am not grasping?

Comment: What is `streams`? Why not iterate with ranged-based for? durationMillis divided by bufferDurationMs gives you the correct size of `streams`?

Comment: What does the crash message say?

Comment: Probably division by zero (check `numberOfBuffers`) or out of bounds access for `input`. You can replace `sum += input[i];` with `sum += input.at(i);` to enforce bounds checking.

Comment: @Rost It is a floating point division and division by zero results in infinity (or nan for 0/0). Only integer division by 0 crashes.

Comment: `getAverage` makes a copy of `std::deque<float>` and that could run out of memory.

Comment: `In my mind it should be exactly the same thing`. No, by passing it into a function by value you are creating a copy. Try passing it as `const deque<float>& input` instead.

Comment: Since you are passing `input` by value (as a copy) that alone might easily change the way undefined behavior manifests itself. I.e both versions are broken (out of bounds access?), but in the first one it is just more instantaneously explicit about it.

Comment: `std::vector<float> result = std::vector<float>(streams.size());` Why copy-initialisation? Just construct the object normally: `std::vector<float> result(streams.size());`

Comment: Otherwise the two examples look equivalent - where's your [MCVE]?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin division by zero is UB in C++ Standard, so it can produce ANY result, including throwing exception, segfaulting or formatting your HDD.

Comment: @Rost The C++ standard defers such details to particular implementation of floating point standard used, because it cannot possibly include such a detailed specification. IEEE 754 specifies exactly what happens. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245885/412080 for more on this.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin No, it clearly says it in 8.6: "If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Once there is undefined behaviour *anywhere* in your program, *any other* part of the program may behave unpredictably. In particular, your program may react to seemingly inconsequential changes in unexpected and violent ways. (You change `x = a + b` to `x = b + a` and your computer explodes). This is one of the reasons a [mcve] is necessary.

Comment: @Rost  The C++ standard is known to be underspecified and it leaves many things outside its scope. I only ever worked on x86 platform with IEEE 754 compliant FPU, where floating point division by 0 is very well defined. I remember the pre-C++11 times when people posted questions about threads and someone would always come and say that threads are undefined behaviour in C++. Pendatically correct, but utterly useless answer in practice. That didn't prevent many useful pre-C++11 applications from using threads correctly.

Comment: Seems like the issue was that I was creating a copy by passing the input to the function. I did not realize this. Still a lot to learn! Thanks for all the quick feedback - first time I post a question in C++ and I am amazed by all the responses.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin That's not the case. Threads weren't mentioned at all in old standard, so they weren't UB, but specific implementation extension. Division by zero is defined as UB.  There are several cases of UB that "work" on most implementations, but they are still UB.

Comment: @Rost UB is what C++ standard doesn't require or define, and threads were UB (according to pedantic people). However, applications don't execute on a abstract C++ machine, rather on a platform with behaviours defined by other standards, such as IEEE 754 and/or POSIX. Most if not all modern general purpose CPUs implement IEEE 754 and naturally C++ doesn't prohibit one to rely on and use those. So, when you say division by 0 is undefined, you may like to be explicit about the platforms where that is the case, otherwise your comment doesn't carry any useful or actionable information.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin looks like you mix up undefined and unspecified behavior. Correct C++ program shall contain no UB because actually it's not predictable what happen. It may differ even for same platform/toolchain with different debug/optimization options. Original question didn't specify the actual platform so it make sense to consider it's general C++ question. And actually x86 floating point division MAY throw hardware exception (resulting in SIGFPE on Linux e.g.) - this depends on FPU flags. See `feenableexcept()` from `fenv.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The program has many potential reasons why it can cause a crash.

   1. `bufferDurationMs` is not initialized in the provided code, I hope its initialized to value other than 0.
   2. `for (int i = 0; i < streams.size(); ++i) {
      result[i] = getAverage(streams[i], numberOfBuffers);  }` use `result.size()` instead of `streams.size()` as result is lvalue. It
      is better to check both of these conditions in for.
   3. It is quite possible that `numberOfBuffers` can be 0 in which case code would crash(divide by zero)
2. Some optimizations that can be done in the code:

   1. `std::vector<float> result = std::vector<float>(streams.size());` use `reserve` rather than using a costly operation of creating a
      vector and assigning it to lvalue.
      std::vector result; result.reserve(streams.size());
   2. `float MyBuffer::getAverage(std::deque<float> input, int numberOfBuffers)` prefer const reference rather than creating a copy
      of an object

      const std::deque& input

Comment: Seems like the main issue was the fact that I was creating a copy of input. Passing `const std::deque<float>& input` solved it.